# Is it possible to detect and recover from a deregistered ECS Task Definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm having trouble managing an INACTIVE ECS task definition using CDK. Furthermore, the CloudFormation drift detection seems to miss this "deregistration".

**Repro**

Put the following into app.py:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    core,
)

class ExampleStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        task_defn = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, "ExampleTaskDefinition", cpu=256, memory_limit_mib=512)
        task_defn.add_container("ExampleContainer", image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"))

app = core.App()
ExampleStack(app, "ExampleStack", env={"region": "us-east-1"})
app.synth()
```

Deploy it:

```
$ cdk deploy
...
 2/4 | 7:10:50 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition | ExampleTaskDefinition (ExampleTaskDefinition47549670)
 2/4 | 7:10:50 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition | ExampleTaskDefinition (ExampleTaskDefinition47549670) Resource creation Initiated
 3/4 | 7:10:51 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition | ExampleTaskDefinition (ExampleTaskDefinition47549670)
 4/4 | 7:10:52 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | ExampleStack

 ✅  ExampleStack

Stack ARN:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:865458870989:stack/ExampleStack/47a559b0-2386-11ea-a6f0-0a4fdb0c1726
...
```

Confirm the task definition:

```
$ aws ecs list-task-definitions --region=us-east-1
{
    "taskDefinitionArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:865458870989:task-definition/ExampleStackExampleTaskDefinition169C2730:1"
    ]
}
```

Deregister the task definition:

```
$ aws ecs deregister-task-definition --task-definition arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:865458870989:task-definition/ExampleStackExampleTaskDefinition169C2730:1  --region=us-east-1
...
  "status": "INACTIVE",
...
```

**Issue 1:** At this point, the CloudFormation drift detection continues to show the task definition as "IN_SYNC".

My guess is that this is because of the way ECS Task Definitions remain discoverable (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/deregister-task-definition.html):
"At this time, INACTIVE task definitions remain discoverable in your account indefinitely"

**Question 1:** Is there a way for CloudFormation to detect this as drift?

**Issue 2:** the CDK is unable to deploy this stack again. For example, if I add an ECS Cluster and Service to app.py:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    core,
)

class ExampleStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        task_defn = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, "ExampleTaskDefinition", cpu=256, memory_limit_mib=512)
        task_defn.add_container("ExampleContainer", image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"))

        cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "ExampleServiceCluster")
        ecs.FargateService(
            self,
            "ExampleService",
            cluster=cluster,
            task_definition=task_defn,
            assign_public_ip=False,
            desired_count=1,
            min_healthy_percent=0,
            max_healthy_percent=100,
            service_name="ExampleService"
        )

app = core.App()
ExampleStack(app, "ExampleStack", env={"region": "us-east-1"})
app.synth()
```

I'll now get the following error:

```
$ cdk deploy
...
 16/27 | 7:18:30 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::Service                     | ExampleService/Service (ExampleServiceC7919DA2) TaskDefinition is inactive (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID: dbb927b6-b2ba-495b-be47-b202a2802465)
        new BaseService (/tmp/jsii-kernel-9athIS/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ecs/lib/base/base-service.js:98:25)
        \_ new FargateService (/tmp/jsii-kernel-9athIS/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ecs/lib/fargate/fargate-service.js:35:9)
...
```

**Question 2:** Is there an easy way to get this stack work again without destroying it completely? I suppose I could also change something about the TaskDefinition (e.g., change the name to "ExampleTaskDefinition1") to trigger the creation of a new ARN, but this seems a bit clunky. Any ideas on a better approach?

Thanks in advance!